# how to prevent from getting undefined index when using GET method

Tags: php

So I have 2 page. `MainFile.php` and `login.php`. In `Mainfile.php` there is an option where you have to choose what warehouse you are in. Every option have values or ID in it.

This is my `MainFile.php`:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Department</h1>
    <label>Choose Warehouse</label><br>
    <select id="wh">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=1">Warehouse 1</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=2">Warehouse 2</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=3">Warehouse 3</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=4">Warehouse 4</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=5">Warehouse 5</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=6">Warehouse 6</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=7">Warehouse 7</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=8">Warehouse 8</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=9">Warehouse 9</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=10">Warehouse 10</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=11">Warehouse 11</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=12">Warehouse 12</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=13">Warehouse 13</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=14">Warehouse 14</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=15">Warehouse 15</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=16">Warehouse 16</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=17">Warehouse 17</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=18">Warehouse 18</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=19">Warehouse 19</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=20">Warehouse 20</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=21">Warehouse 21</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=22">Warehouse 22</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=23">Warehouse 23</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=24">Warehouse 24</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=25">Warehouse 25</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=26">Warehouse 26</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=27">Warehouse 27</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=28">Warehouse 28</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=29">Warehouse 29</option>
        <option value="login_WH.php?whID=30">Warehouse 30</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In `login.php`, I will get the ID of the option in the `MainFile.php` that I will be using to determine if this user is on warehouse 1,2,3 etc., then redirect the user to the `homepage` if the username, password and ID match my record in the database. I don't get any error in my code unless I will input an incorrect username or password. It will be too inconvenient if user will go to `Mainfile.php` just to get the ID to not get error when login in.

This is my code in `login.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="login_WH.php" autocomplete="off">

    <?php echo display_error(); ?>

    <?php

        $id = $_GET["whID"];
        $_SESSION["whID"] = $id;
    ?>

    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="15">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15">
    </div>
        <input type="text" name="whID" class="hide" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_btn_wh">Login</button>
    </div>
    <p>
        Not your department? <a href="MainFile.php">Go back</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I can't post the picture because of my low reputation. but I get the "Notice: Undefined index: whID in C:\xampp\htdocs\project2\login_WH.php on line 29" in the line in `login.php` "$id = $_GET["whID"];"
I've tried to use session but I think its not working (or I just used it wrong?). Any help will be appreciated! btw sorry for my english, I hope you understand my question.

Comment: PD of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/4261133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$_GET` parameter is not getting set. `$_GET` gets the `whID` parameter from the *URL*. Unless you are manually navigating to the pages such as `login_WH.php?whID=1`, `login_WH.php?whID=2`, etc., then the `$_GET` parameter will never get set.

What I *believe* you're intending to do is link off to each warehouse individually from `MainPage.php`:

```
<a href="login_WH.php?whID=1">Warehouse 1</a>
<a href="login_WH.php?whID=2">Warehouse 2</a>
```

Then on the `login.php` script you will be able to receive the `$_GET["whID"]` parameter. You can also additionally check this with **[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["whID"] && !empty($_GET["whID"])) {
   $id = $_GET["whID"];
} else {
  // Redirect or throw an error
}
```

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? how can I store the data from ID using session?